# What is the name of the MKDM first opening?

Tags: miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid

I have no idea what it is, and I need some help because I like the song.

Comment: For future reference, Anime OP's and ED's are, almost always, easy to find via a quick Google search. The downvotes are most likely because this question 'does not show research effort' so I suggest that next time, you at least try to find it for yourself and if you really can't find it, post it here and show what you tried to do to find it so people can suggest other methods you might not have tried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick Google for `kobayashi dragon maid OP` gives us that the song is 青空のラプソディ / "Aozora no Rhapsody" aka "Rhapsody of Blue Sky", by fhána.

Comment: and generally [Wikipedia lists OPs and EDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Kobayashi%27s_Dragon_Maid#Anime) for anime and almost always is the first google result for the series. otherwise [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=18807) is the next best place